# Generic Repository interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have this interface:

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, I> {

}
```

However I can't add these methods since they clash:

```
boolean remove(final T object);

boolean remove(final I id);
```

Is it possible to fix this? T is type and I is id type.

Comment: For me the best way to fix that is to have more descriptive method names, like removeById

Comment: Won't id always be a Long or Integer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know that T and I will be constrained by certain type hierarchies ? In that case you could use this.

```
class Myclass<K extends ClassA ,V extends ClassB>
{
    private void remove(K k){}
    private void remove(V V){}
}
```

I'd agree with @Luciano also. Remove ambiguity where possible. It will improve code readability.